# Pass struct as generic type and access that generic types properties

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui

I'm working on a Swift package where an option will be to pass in a generic type (`Person`) and then that `GenericStruct` can use properties on that type passed in. The issue obviously is that the generic `T` has no idea what's being passed in. **Is there a way to define the property to access on the generic type `T`?**

```swift
struct Person: Equatable {
    var name: String
    var height: Double
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var james = Person(name: "James", height: 175.0)
    
    var body: some View {
        GenericStruct(person: $james)
    }
}

struct GenericStruct<T: Equatable>: View {
    @Binding var person: T
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(person.name)) // This line.
    }
}
```

I want to specifically pass in which property to access on `Person` when passing it to `GenericStruct`. The property won't always be `name` it could be anything I define within `Person`. For example:

```swift
GenericStruct(person: $james, use: Person.name)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't this exactly a protocol?

```
protocol NameProviding {
    var name: String { get }
}

struct GenericStruct<T: Equatable & NameProviding>: View { ... }
```

Or is there a more subtle part of the question?

---

The best way to do this is to pass a String Binding:

```
struct GenericStruct: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)) // This line.
    }
}

GenericStruct(text: $james.name)
```

But it is possible with key paths. It's just a bit more awkward and less flexible in this particular case:

```
// Should be the syntax, but I haven't double-checked it.
struct GenericStruct<T: Equatable>: View {
    @Binding var person: T
    var use: KeyPath<T, String>
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(person[keyPath: use]))
    }
}

GenericStruct(person: $james, use: \.name)
```

Comment: The type that's passed in could be anything, it won't necessarily have `name`. It could be something like `Person(name: String, height: Double, age: Int)` and then I would want to be able to access either `name`, `height` or `age` on that passed in value. I want to specifically be able to define which property to access when calling `GenericStruct`

Comment: Can you give an example of what the calling code would look like? I can't picture what "calling GenericStruct" means. You generally don't "call" `body`, so it feels like there's more than your example going on.

Comment: `GenericStruct(person: $james, use: Person.name)` then `GenericStruct` would access `.name` on the passed in `Person`

Comment: I assume that `.name` is required to be a String property, right? (Otherwise you couldn't make use of it in the call to Text). This is doable, but just passing a String Binding is easier and more flexible: `GenericStruct(string: $james.name)`.

Comment: `KeyPath` worked, thank you!